# Python: Date compare fails equality test

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner. Here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
matexp = input("What's the material expiration date (mm/dd/yy): ")
matexpir = datetime.strptime(matexp, "%m/%d/%y")

d1 = datetime.today()

d2 = timedelta(days=30)

d3 = d1 + d2

if matexpir == d3:
    matstat = "CAUTION"
elif matexpir <= d1:
    matstat = "EXPIRED"
else :
    matstat = "Null"
```

While testing this code, I can get it to print matstat or Status = 'EXPIRED' on a table, but when I try to get it to print 'CAUTION', it doesn't and goes straight to 'Null'. Why is that? How may I fix it? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Double check that `d3` doesn’t include the *time*.  Comparing a date and datetime will never be equal.

Comment: it's probably safer to do `if matexpir <=d1` followed by `elif matexpir <= d3` instead; but like yeah, it looks like you haven't removed the time part of date time so the `==` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, the test is comparing a **date** and a **datetime**, which will obviously never be equal.

To address this, the comparison should be like-for-like. Compare **dates**, with the time factor removed.

---

#### The fix:

Change this:

```
matexpir = datetime.strptime(matexp, "%m/%d/%y")
```

to:

```
matexpir = datetime.strptime(matexp, "%m/%d/%y").date()
```

And change this:

```
d1 = datetime.today()
```

to:

```
d1 = datetime.today().date()
```

---

#### Full solution:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

matexp = input("What's the material expiration date (mm/dd/yy): ")
matexpir = datetime.strptime(matexp, "%m/%d/%y").date()

d1 = datetime.today().date()
d2 = timedelta(days=30)
d3 = d1 + d2

if matexpir == d3:
    matstat = "CAUTION"
elif matexpir <= d1:
    matstat = "EXPIRED"
else:
    matstat = "Null"
```

Comment: This solution worked, thank you very much. I learned something new.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help!  (As SO protocol) feel free to accept the answer by clicking the tick.